# Why is the time complexity O(n^2) rather than O(n^3)?

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

I solved [a problem on LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/description/), and I found [an answer](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/22619/python-easy-to-understand-solution-o-n-n-time/27) of which time complexity is O(n^2), why? Here is the code

```
class Solution(object):
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        result = []
        nums.sort()
        for i in xrange(len(nums)-2):
            if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i-1]:
                continue
            l, r = i + 1, len(nums) - 1
            while l < r:
                if nums[l] + nums[r] == -nums[i]:
                    result.append([nums[i], nums[l], nums[r]])
                    l, r = l + 1, r - 1
                    while l < r and nums[l] == nums[l-1]:
                        l += 1
                    while l < r and nums[r] == nums[r+1]:
                        r -= 1
                elif nums[l] + nums[r] > -nums[i]:
                    r -= 1
                else:
                    l += 1
        return result
```

Comment: Because for each `i` in the array you loop only once through left side of `i` and once through right side of `i` (that's what the inner `while l < r` loop does). Thus you have O(n^2).

Comment: @freakish, thanks but there is `while l < r and nums[l] == nums[l-1]:` in the loop of `while l < r`.

Comment: Since you're programming in Python then you should really have the `python` tag. If you want a generic and language-agnostic answer, then use pseudo-code and add the `language-agnostic` tag. Oh, and the `big-o` tag should probably be added as well.

Comment: @AlexanderYau The most inner `while` loop only complements the middle loop. Note that for each `i` each other element is "touched" only once in these nested loops. In other words inner loops are not independent.